# Modules communication in multi module android app

Tags: android, modularization

I try to realise multi module android app.

I read modularization documentation section which is started [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/modularization). There is Figure3 in [feature modules section](https://developer.android.com/topic/modularization/patterns#feature-modules). This figure demonstrates connections between `:feature` and `:data` modules. I have `:domain` module which is included use cases. My `:domain` module has `:data` module as dependency(in domain module build.gradle).

I use scheme similar to [nowinandroid](https://github.com/android/nowinandroid) project. Here is scheme of dependencies:

[image: scheme of dependencies]

**My question is: How should I use use cases in `:auth` module?**

Comment: By importing domain module?

Comment: @m0skit0 what do you mean "by importing"? Using "import" directive or use DI?

Comment: @m0skit0 probably is talking about `implementation project(path: ':domain')`

Comment: Another (I think) way you could achieve that would be a bit similar to the way you would navigate between feature modules, so by using interfaces (more on that here: https://medium.com/@nicholas.rose/multi-module-navigation-with-dagger2-f747db186343)